# SQLMap realy slow on local network

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, sqlmap

i'am currently trying to use SQLMap on an apparently easy injection on a local web server :

```
SELECT * from table WHERE `col` LIKE 'VULN_HERE';
```

I'am using the following command :

```
sqlmap -u http://localhost/?i=1 --dbms mysql --level 5 --risk 3 -p i --dbs -v 2 --technique 'T'
```

When running this command, sqlmap identify the injection correctly but is blocking at :

```
[14:36:43] [INFO] checking if the injection point on GET parameter 'i' is a false positive
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your URL shall be quoted :

`sqlmap -u "http://localhost/?i=1" ....`

Answer (score 0):

Hi check your syntax and have a look:

[SQLmap](http://www.sqlinjection.net/sqlmap/tutorial/)
You need your **URL** to be within *quotes* always or the command prompt will take **i=1** outside the **URL** and as a different parameter.
Hope it'll solve your issues.